# JQuery tiered Autocomplete that does not set data for the next tier

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an Autocomplete for state and province names running.  I want to pass the state abbreviation to the next cascade of Autocomplete.  I created a hidden input and I want to set it to the abbreviation when the state name is selected, then I'll select the abbreviation for use in the next tier Autocomplete to limit the city query to one state only.  At a prior step, I have country radio buttons setting a state limit in the .ajax data option, so you can see (generally) what I want to do in this state/city tier. I've tried several things, done a lot of Google searching and reading jQuery books, but I need some help. The stateProvince input box autocompletes and selects the full state name.  The hidden input does not get set with the abbreviation. The alert is empty. I'm not sure about either the ajax success or the ajax select functions. How do I get the abbreviation (not the name) to be the value of the hidden input? and how can I then select it in the next tier's .ajax data option?  Here is the relevant code.

selected HTML without tag symbols:

input type="text" id="stateProvince" name="stateProvince" size="50" maxlength="50" 
input type="hidden" id="hiddenState" name="hiddenState"

Autocomplete source ajax;

```
    $("#stateProvince").autocomplete
    ({
        source: function( request, response )
        {                           
            //Pass the selected country to the php to limit the stateProvince selection to just that country  
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "getStateProvince.php",
                data: {
                        term: request.term, 
                        country: $('input[name=country]:checked').val()    //Pass the selected country to php
                      },       
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( data )
                {                                          
                    response( $.map( data, function( item )
                    {
                        return{                                   
                                label: item.stateName,
                                value: item.name,
                                abbrev: item.stateAbbrev                                                                   
                               }
                    }));
                },
                select: function( event,ui )
                {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                $("#hiddenState").$(this).val(ui.item.abbrev);
                }
            });
            alert('|' + $("#hiddenState").val() + '|2nd');  //doesn't trigger here; shows no content when placed in the next tier Autocomplete              
        },           
        minLength: 2
    });
```

JSON example returned from php:

[{"stateName":"Alabama","name":"Alabama","stateAbbrev":"AL"},{"stateName":"Alaska","name":"Alaska","stateAbbrev":"AK"}]

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it! I see the following problems:

1. `select` is an event on the `autocomplete` widget. Your code as it is right now is defining `select` as an option to the `$.ajax({...});` call.
2. The `alert` statement that's failing is inside the `source` function to the autocomplete widget. I'm guessing it pops up right after you start typing. The reason it's empty is because it is not inside the `select` function (and it takes place *before* your AJAX call comes back successfully).

You can tweak your code as follows:

```
$("#stateProvince").autocomplete
({
    source: function( request, response )
    {                           
        //Pass the selected country to the php to limit the stateProvince selection to just that country  
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "getStateProvince.php",
            data: {
                    term: request.term, 
                    country: $('input[name=country]:checked').val()    //Pass the selected country to php
                  },       
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data )
            {                                          
                response( $.map( data, function( item )
                {
                    return{                                   
                            label: item.stateName,
                            value: item.name,
                            abbrev: item.stateAbbrev                                                                   
                           }
                }));
            }
        });             
    },      
    select: function( event,ui )
    {
        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        $("#hiddenState").val(ui.item.abbrev);
        alert('|' + $("#hiddenState").val() + '|2nd');  //doesn't trigger here; shows no content when placed in the next tier Autocomplete 
    },     
    minLength: 2
});
```

Note the location of the `alert` statement and the `select` event handler.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your help.  The alert now triggers and gives me [object, Object].  I have another alert in the next tier and it says the same.  However, the state abbreviation is not getting passed into the next tier. (if I 'hard code' a state abbreviation, it works) In the select function, I have tried ui.item.abbrev, ui.item.stateAbbrev, and ui.item[2].  I can't tell if the problem is setting the value in the hidden input, or getting it.  How do I debug this?

Comment: @Mike_Laird: I've noticed an error in the `select` event handler, I will update my answer

Comment: @Mike_Laird: Additionally, if you're using Firebug with Firefox you can set a breakpoint and inspect the value of `ui.item` to see if the `abbrev` property is there at all.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: A breakpoint on the abbrev line in success shows correct state abbrevs. A breakpoint on the alert in select displays the abbrev. Normally, select displays state name in the box. So I believe the hiddenState input is set correctly. I could not find ui.item.abbrev or the value of the hidden input in the Firebug stuff to read directly. Maybe you could suggest where to look. My current problem hunch is in the 3d tier getting the hidden data.  I have a data: line very similar to the one above. adminCode1: "AK", creates Alaska responses. adminCode1: $("#hiddenState").val(), fails

Comment: @Mike_Laird: You can actually type a jQuery selector directly in the console. So if you type `$(#hiddenState").val()`, you should get the state abbreviation. If that returns what you expect, maybe adding the code that's not working to your question would help.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: In Firebug's script section, a watch on $("#hiddenState").val($(this).val(ui.item.abbrev)); says it is undefined - as best I can tell. I'm a novice and not sure of how to use or read Firebug. Maybe the select: option is not working to set the hidden input. It does set the state name in the text box.  I tried Firebug's DOM section. I can find references to the hidden input, but no reference to its value. I will post the jQuery code for both the 2d and 3d tier in an answer below. They're pretty similar. The 3d tier works when 'hard coded' with a state abbreviation.

Comment: @Mike_Laird: Make sure to update the original post--don't add a new answer.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: Ooops, too late.  I'll get it right next time.

Comment: @Mike_Laird: Hmm... Are you sure your input's `id` is `hiddenState`? (`<input type="hidden" id="hiddenState" />`). Also make sure that you use `$("#hiddenState").val(ui.item.abbrev);` not `$("#hiddenState").val($(this).val(ui.item.abbrev));`

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: Getting rid of $(this) did it!  Works like a charm. I am still confused by $(this) and will have to work on it again.  Thanks so much for your help.  You can't imagine how long I have been working on these few lines, but I started from no knowledge at all about Javascript. Thanks, again!

Comment: @Mike_Laird: No problem! Glad to hear you figured it out. Please accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for both the 2d state tier and 3d city tier of the Autocomplete.

```
    //2d tier - stateProvince: autocomplete selection
    //set the country for the 2nd tier to select stateProvince from only the country selected in the 1st tier         
    $("#stateProvince").autocomplete
    ({ 
        source: function( request, response )
        {                          
            //Pass the selected country to the php query manager to limit the stateProvince selection to just that country                                               
            $.ajax(
            { 
                url: "getStateProvince.php",
                data: {
                        term: request.term,   
                        country: $('input[name=country]:checked').val()    //Pass the selected country to php
                      },        
                type: "POST",  // a jQuery ajax POST transmits in querystring format in utf-8
                dataType: "json",   //return data in json format                                                                                                                                                        
                success: function( data ) 
                {                                           
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) 
                    {
                        return{                                    
                                label: item.stateName,
                                value: item.name,
                                abbrev: item.stateAbbrev                                                                    
                               }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function( event,ui )
        {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            $("#hiddenState").val($(this).val(ui.item.abbrev));
            //alert('|' + $("#hiddenState").val() + '|1st');  //shows [object,Object] 
        },      
        minLength: 2
    });

    //3d tier - city: autocomplete selection  //                        
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete
    ({                 
        source: function( request, response ) 
        {              
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: 
                {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    country: $('input[name=country]:checked').val(),
                    adminCode1: $("#hiddenState").val(), //"AK", //works-delivers only Alaska towns.
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 10,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },

                success: function( data ) 
                {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) 
                    {
                        return{
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : "") + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : "") + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "")
                               }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) 
            {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                //ui.item.option.selected = true;
                //self._trigger( "selected", event, {item: ui.item.option});
            },  //combo box demo uses this to bar illegal input. Other things are needed also. item.option is not defined
        minLength: 2,


        open: function() 
        {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() 
        {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```